# IRemoteApplication.terminateRunningInstances + windows phone 8.1 appx

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When an .appx is running on a WP 8.1 simulator, the `IRemoteApplication.TerminateRunningInstances` API doesn't do anything.
No exception is raised, just nothing happens, and the app stays running.

Is there any way to fix?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see that API documented on MSDN. Where does it come from?

Comment: Probably undocumented. It comes from Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.Interface.dll

Comment: Probably left over from the Windows CE days. For what purpose are you trying to kill the apps on the phone? I wonder if you could automate Visual Studio to do it for you

Comment: It worked OK on WP 8.0, and it still works on WP 8.1 when the app is Silverlight *.XAP.

I'm working on a UI test automation product.